# Grunt Task "default" not found

Tags: gruntjs

I'm new to use grunt, I just create a real sample to run. But I get blocked my A warning `Warning: Task "default" not found`

I just copied sample from http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

My package is

```
{
  "name": "my-project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0"
  }
}
```

my Gruntfile.js is

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.registerTask('default', 'Log some stuff.', function() {
        grunt.log.write('Logging some stuff...').ok();
    });

};
```

it just print some simple log, why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the pasting the code from the grunt page won't do anything by itself. Did you first install grunt by console: **npm install -g grunt-cli** ?

Grunt is a task runner; that is, it does not have the ability to do the task itself, but starts the program listed in the gruntfile, runs the program on the noted files or folders, and stops each task before going on to the next.

You'll need to make sure that the JSHint program has been installed on your system before running grunt, or grunt won't run that task. You'll enter this in your console to install it: **npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev**

Grunt doesn't know what files to run JSHint on, so you'll need to tell it where to look. To do that, you'll need to carefully read the grunt-contrib-jshint page in the npm plugins site at http://gruntjs.com/plugins.

In addition, JSHint has these options: http://jshint.com/docs/options/ You'll need to learn the correct syntax to put them in the gruntfile.

Grant makes repetitive tasks simpler, but you'll still need to do a bit of homework to put all the different pieces together to get it working for you.

I wrote a complete article on getting started in grunt, based on my own learning: https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2016/10/31/how-to-use-grunt-to-automate-repetitive-tasks/